# Unable to install apk with CompileSDKVersion 'android-Q'

Tags: java, android

"I tried to install my apk but it was giving this message.
Package seems to be corrupted.
this is my build.gradle file". However when I changed my compilesdkversion to 28 it was running. On directly running the app from android studio it is running but after generation apk it is not installing?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 'android-Q'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.deskneedui"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:dc-volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Yeah, mine issue was solved. I downloaded sdk for api 29 and did what the answer below told me.

Answer (score 1):

To fully test your app's compatibility with [**Android Q**](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk) and begin using new APIs, open your ***module-level*** `build.gradle` file and update the **`compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion`** as shown below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }

}
```

**FYI**

Your **`classpath`** will be

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

**`distributionUrl`** will be

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```